# log4net: Logging XML as string

Tags: c#, xml, oracle, character-encoding, log4net

I am experiencing a strange problem when I log the XML contents to the database.
I have a table in Oracle 9i which has a CLOB column. I am logging the contents of my input XML to this column. When I log XML, additional characters are getting logged to the column.

**This is my source XML file:**

```
<Root BatchUploadType="Contract">
  <VOContractBatch>
    <Reference>Xavier Leasing Company</Reference>
    <Originator>Data Migrator</Originator>
    <ContractPackages>
      <VOContractPackagesCollection>
        <VOContractPackage>
          <Contract>
            <Customer Name="Omega Paper Products" Id="100901"/>
          </Contract>
        </VOContractPackage>
      </VOContractPackagesCollection>
    </ContractPackages>
  </VOContractBatch>
</Root>
```

**When I log this to the DB, I am getting an output that looks like this.**
[image: output]

I am reading the XML from a file. The encoding of this file is set to ANSI.
Where should I be looking?

Comment: It seems it is logged in UTF-16 for some reason.

Comment: @svick when I open the file in notepad++, it tells me that the encoding is set to ANSI.

Comment: How are you getting the XML from the Column into Notepad++?

Comment: @Conrad I am using PL/SQL Developer which lets me query CLOB columns and save their contents to a text file.

Comment: maybe you should try writing a scratch C# app to retrieve the CLOB data and see if your results are different